# border-radius и дочерние элементы

Tags: css

Если у дива определен border-radius, почему этот радиус не наследуется дочерним дивом, углы которого начинают выходить за пределы родителя?

**http://jsfiddle.net/TFqqU/1/**

Что делать? У дочернего элемента тоже определять border-radius?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте к родителю просто owerflow. http://jsfiddle.net/TFqqU/2/

Comment: @dimka3210, это круто, спасибо. overflow, я думал, вообще к этому не относится, а применяется только в случае скроллинга. Так и не понял, каким оно боком здесь.

Comment: Только некоторые браузеры (Опера, например) не воспринимают `overflow` с `border-radius` как задумано

Comment: Странно, что тогда делать с Оперой? В дочерних элементах тоже указывать соответстующий border?